# On Form Submission, do jquery checking first before Codeiginiter validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

Form submission button, I have to check some validation using jquery. However I have also used codeiginiter validation with form_open(xxxx), which makes my submit button jQuery has not been called. How can I do to make both works? before or after? (I want front and backend checking)

```
<?php $prevURLPATH=urlencode($p); echo form_open('form/'.$usr.'/'.$name.'?prevURL='.$p); ?>


<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center"></label>
<div class="col-md-8"> 
<button id="submit-upload-form" class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" onclick="setup(); return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
<button id="validate" hidden="true" type="submit"></button>
</div>
</div>


function setup()
{ .......Checking some fields in the form...............}
```

What I want is:
On Form Submission, Jquery/JS checking (Frontend), then backend codeigniter form checking.

(It seems like when user click the submit button, it ignores all the jquery validation and go straight to codeigniter validation. I think if I use form_open() in php I am very limited right?)

I am following this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

Hoping to find an answer so that other people will know the right way of working with codeiginiter validation.

Thanks for all your answers so far, however I still couldn't find the right solution yet. :( Anyone else please help?

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` in your jquery function

Comment: You can bind any function to the click of a button. It doesn't matter if this button is a submit, the binding won't stop the submission from happening.  I've tested my answer and it works: it triggers first the jQuery function and then the form validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate in the client before submitting your form, the following will work:

```
// view
echo form_open('basic_controller/submission');
echo form_input( array('name'=>'text', 'id'=>'text_input') );
echo form_submit('my_submit', 'Enter', "id='my_submit'");
echo form_close();

// controller
function submission() {
    $field = $this->input->post('text');
    // add your checkings (backend)
}
```

So far, this is what you already had but simpler.
Note that fields on the form have an ID. We can now manipulate and access the content of the form easily via jQuery. Add a click handler on the submit button:

```
    // view
    <script type='text/javascript'>    
        $(document).on('click', '#my_submit', function() {        
            var input_value = $('#text_input').val();

            // do your frontend checkings here
            alert('before form submission. ' + input_value);
        });
    </script>
```

Actually, there is no need to give the fields an ID, you only have to assign an ID to the submit button and then access the fields in some other way (I just did that for the sake of simplicity).

---

**EDIT**

In your case, the script should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-upload-form', function() {
    setup();
});
```

Comment: Still didn't trigger jquery checking.

Comment: @RyanFung I've clarified a little bit what you should do in your case. Please take a look at the EDIT

Comment: it seems like you are trying to use the click handler to prevent form submission. Regardless of what you put in your click function (action handler), the submit still goes through.

Comment: @RyanFung I'm not trying to prevent form submission.  I'm executng a javascript function right before the form submission (and therefore, codeigniter's validation).  I thought that was what you asked for. Have you tried this workaround?

Answer (score 2):

here is example try with that one..hope worked for you..

```
<?php
$attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');
$prevURLPATH=urlencode($p); echo form_open('form/'.$usr.'/'.$name.'?prevURL='.$p,$attributes); ?>
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center"></label>
<div class="col-md-8"> 
<button id="submit-upload-form" class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
         alert('hi');
        //write your validation code here. and make sure about jquery library is loaded.
        return false;
    });
}};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried preventing the form submission, but no luck using this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can stick with [jquery.validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). It's convention is similar to [html5 methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/) to validate form. Every modern browser supports this methods, so maybe you can even ommit jquery plugin, and rely on codeigniter validation as the last resort if somebody switched off javascript.

With jquery plugin you have more customization, while html5 validation brings its own messages and styles.

I think there's also a problem with your example, there are no inputs, so what we validate exactly. Giving upload class sugests that there will be file upload happening.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" required/>
```

Also jquery plugin has method for [upload validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/).

There can be some issue with your form. Do you close it? And it has misterious action thing. Maybe it should be form_open_multipart() if there are any files, remember that form_open produces POST method form. And what about this url inside action: form/'.$usr.'/'.$name.'?prevURL='.$p . Maybe try to improve controller and routing.

By the way. Working with jquery validate is as easy as putting html5 rules inside inputs and adding script at the bottom.

```
<script>
$("#your_form").validate();
</script>
```

And the last thing. If you use jquery plugin, remember to load jquery before loading plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

For that there's a plugins written and maintained by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of the jQuery team, lead developer on the jQuery UI team and maintainer of QUnit. It was started back in the early days of jQuery in 2006, and updated and improved since then.

Bundled with a lot of examples you can play with

Put something like this in your header,

```
<script src="<?php echo YOUT_PATH.'jquery-1.12.2.js'; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo YOUR_PATH.'bootstrap.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo YOUT_PATH.'jquery-validation-1.15.0/dist/jquery.validate.js'; ?>"></script>
```

In your form, will be similar to this

```
<?php echo form_open('form/'.$usr.'/'.$name.'?prevURL='.urlencode($p), array('class'=>'form-horizontal','class'=>'signupForm')); ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-4">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" name="signup" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<?php form_close(); ?>
```

and in your footer put similar to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#signupForm" ).validate( {
  rules: {
    // Rules Here
  },
  messages: {
    // Messages here
  },
  errorElement: "em",
  errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
    // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
    error.addClass( "help-block" );

    if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
      error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
    } else {
      error.insertAfter( element );
    }
  },
  highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
  },
  unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
  }
});
</script>
```

You can read how it will be properly use in this link,
  http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: It doesn't have to work, js is a different level of validation. Only thing to care here are the css classes - they should be consistent across application and you probably should stick to one way of showing errors (all in one place or one by every input).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with following code.

```
<form id="formId" action="path">HTML</form>
<script>
$("#formId").submit(function(){
  //validation
  return false;
});
<script>
```

but when i swap the id and action it simply worked.

```
<form  action="path" id="formId"></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the form before your script and this will work. Try following code-

```
<?php $prevURLPATH=urlencode($p); echo form_open('form/'.$usr.'/'.$name.'?prevURL='.$p); ?>


<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center"></label>
<div class="col-md-8"> 
<button id="submit-upload-form" class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" onclick="setup(); return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
<button id="validate" hidden="true" type="submit"></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<script>
function setup()
{ .......Checking some fields in the form...............}
</script>
```

Comment: Just the same code. Is there any code updated and posted??

Comment: @WingHingRaymondChiu Code is not the same as posted by ryan. Just take a closer look. </form> and <script></script> tags are additional and making a difference.

Comment: @ShoaibAkhter I am still not getting how to stop the codeigniter validation before the jquery validation on form submission.

Comment: @RyanFung Codeigniter validation will only work if the form submits. The code above will not submit the form and stops the codeigniter validation before the jquery validation. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/d4L9eh0z/16/

Comment: @ShoaibAkhter I am trying to do jquery checking before submitting to backend for codeigniter validation.. Therefore I don't think you have answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove your submit button and you put a validation function on a button like you did for

```
<button id="submit-upload-form" class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" onclick="setup(); return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
```

And your setup function checks like this :

```
function setup(){
  //do your verification stuff
  if (valid){
    $("#yourFormId").submit();
  }

}
```

Comment: that is pretty much what I had, which is not working :(

Comment: If you remove the submit button, there's no way your form is submitted by itself.. You must have done somehting wrong

Comment: That's what is it happening. Any suggestion why?

Comment: Can't figure out why - take a look at this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/APz7lNuMULmMdJ0CRPsX?p=preview . It's a very basic example of what you have to do..